# Java POI api to update excel data in background without closing excel?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, background-process, auto-update

Is there any way to update excel content in background when the sheet is in open state.
I am using [`Apache POI Spreadsheet`](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/) API (java based API) to read and write content in excel sheet. 
By using [`user API`](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#user_api), I am saving data to excel sheet, but I didn't find any API to update excel data in background(without closing excel file, content should be updated).
If we try to update excel when it's open it'll show `error like file is accessed by other resource`.
Please help me to find an API to achieve this by using Apache POI or any other API.
(I observed by using `VB script` we can achieve this. but first preference is Java, if there is no other API available then `VB Script`).

Answer (score 1):

Excel puts a lock on the file and thus actively prevents other applications from changing the file, so I don't think this is possible with any library.